# Store byte[] in MongoDB using Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I insert a document into a collection with a field of byte[]. When I query the inserted document to get that field, it returns a different byte[]. How do I fix that?

```
byte[] inputBytes = ...

MongoCollection<Document> collection = _db.getCollection("collectionx");
Document doc = new Document("test", 1).append("val", inputBytes);
collection.insertOne(doc.getDocument());

MongoCursor<Document> result = collection.find(eq("test", 1)).iterator();
Document retrived_doc = cursor.next();
cursor.close();

byte[] outputBytes = ((Binary)retrived_doc.get("val")).getData();

// inputBytes = [B@719f369d
// outputBytes = [B@7b70cec2
```

Comment: What is 'different'? Can you post expected vs. actual results?

Comment: Expect outputBytes to be the same as inputBytes

Comment: But you are just comparing the `toString()`-results of input and output arrays. These just reflect their addresses in memory, not their contents. Why do you think these addresses should be identical?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can encode byte array and store it in doc also decode it after extraction to retrieve original.

```
static String   encodeBase64String(byte[] binaryData)
```

Encodes binary data using the base64 algorithm but does not chunk the output.

```
static byte[]   decodeBase64(String base64String)
```

Decodes a Base64 String into octets.

Please refer this link - https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html

Comment: So mongo is not supporting []byte... the more I learn this DB the more I hate it.

Comment: Use org.bson.types.Binary. Example: new Document("data", new Binary(byteArray)); Even though, it seems to me that it saves it in the db as base64. Not particurarly space efficient.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is not your code but how you check if both arrays - input and output array - are equal. It seems you are just comparing the results of calling `toString()` on both results. But `toString()` is not overridden for array types, so it is actually [`Object.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) which just returns the type and hash code of an object:

> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of
>   the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign
>   character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash
>   code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal
>   to the value of:
>
> ```
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

So `[B@719f369d` means: 'Array of bytes' (`[B`) with hash code `0x719f369d`. It has nothing to do with the array content.

In your example, input and output arrays are two different objects, hence they have different memory addresses and hash codes (due to the fact, that `hashCode()` is also not overridden for array types).

**Solution**

If you want to compare the contents of two byte arrays, call [`Arrays.equals(byte[], byte[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals-byte:A-byte:A-).

If you want to print the content of a byte array, call [`Arrays.toString(byte[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-byte:A-) to convert the content into a human readable `String`.

Answer (score 5):

MongoDB has support `org.bson.types.Binary` type

You can use:

`BasicDBObject("_id", Binary(session.getIp().getAddress()))`

the binary comparisons will work